# Existing alternate PHPDoctor doclets or styles?

Tags: php

We are about to start using [PHPDoctor](http://peej.github.com/phpdoctor/) to auto-generate documentation for our PHP codebase at work. (It was the only one we've tried that could handle our very large codebase, and unlike PHPDocumentor, it's still being updated and supports PHP 5.3).

We'd like to try using different doclets and/or stylesheets than the default that come with it. I did some Googling but didn't see where anybody has posted any. Before we make our own, does anybody know a place where they can be found online?

Answer (score 0):

If you do create your own, we'd love to see it and add it into the project if it's something other people would benefit from.